# Bulk upload of products (multi variants)

Tags: xml, e-commerce, ebay-api

I was looking over all eBay documentations and SDK capabilities and found no option to do either:

1. Set up a scheduled product feed pull from my URL and update listing every X minutes (like Facebook does)
2. Find an API endpoint that receives bulk creation of products in listing, categorized by category name I'd provide

The only things I could find was:

1. Upload manually product feed which takes 30min to process
2. Create a single product in listing via sending XML request

To be sane, I have nearly 50k products and 150k variants, with active website constantly selling these and a massive stock deduction.

Is there a way to connect my product feed and start selling on eBay in a more automatic way? Or it's meant to be a manual work of uploading CSV files and deducting stock manually as well, right?

Can anybody point me to a documentation I could miss? Or just tell me this is not possible the way I expect eBay to work:-)

Comment: The easy way would look into something like M2E (or others similar to it), this can pull your products from other sources (amazon, magento, etc) and can sync your inv/create new products from existing ones. There are ways to programmatically send info to ebay, but id suggest hiring someone with experience in this. As this would take a good knowledge of programming to pull, format, and then push everything that you need.

Comment: M2E is for Magento. We're using SAP hybris. There's a team of 10 developers behind the whole story, just can't find an acceptable way of automating product feed upload ... and we don't want it to be over 200mb file size (if we're talking about XML and not JSON/CSV)

Answer (score 0):

You can request access to eBay LMS (Large Merchant Services API)

[Large Merchant Services](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/large-merchant-services/Concepts/LMS_APIGuide.html)